# View iPhone's PVRTC images on OS X

Tags: iphone, macos, pvrtc

I need to view some of PVRTC-compressed textures from iPhone application (*.pvr) on OS X.

Is there a viewer or format converter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest solution I've found is to run Imagination's [PVRTexTool](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp) for Windows using [Darwine (now WineBottler)](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/).

**Edit:** As gmaclachlan points out, the PVRTexTool zip file now includes OS X versions of both the command line tool and the GUI (which runs under X11); so you no longer have to mess with WineBottler.

You'll need to [register as an Imagination developer](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-register.asp) before you can download PVRTexTool (it's free).

Once you set it up, it's pretty painless and it gives you a decent GUI for working with PVRs.

Comment: Works great with CrossOver as well. Thanks!

Comment: There's a Mac OS version of this tool that runs under the X11 environment (optional install with Mac OS) and there is also a quicklook plug-in here: http://www.limbicsoftware.com/quickpvr.html It's more convenient, but not quite as accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX Yosemite (and maybe a couple versions earlier) has built-in preview of PVR files.