# How to convert an image to PVRTC format

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pvrtc

I've been using terminal to convert my `jpg` image named left to `pvrtc` format and this happens:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o left.pvrtc left.jpg  
Failed to load image  
Failed to perform Encode
```

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671680/pvr-texturetool-build-phase. So, do you have spaces anywhere in the full path to the images?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o left.pvrtc left.jpg
```

To:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -o left.pvr left.PNG
```

The file must be a PNG

Updated instructions on OSX 10.10+

In Terminal, hit `cd` to make sure you're in your root directory.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ && ls
```

This should show you a list of all the tools there (Make sure you see `texturetool`) - If you don't, update your OS, then Xcode

Once you know it's there, `cd` back to your root and run the tool like:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool -e PVRTC --bits-per-pixel-2 -f PVR -o [new path to pvr to go] [path of original png]`

Your **output** `pvr` path can be `~/whatever/image.pvr` and your **input** `png` is the path to your image *to be* converted.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671680/pvr-texturetool-build-phase?lq=1) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670338/view-iphones-pvrtc-images-on-os-x?rq=1) are other good walkthrough

> The `iPhone SDK` includes a tool that allows you to create textures in the PVRTC compression format, aptly named `texturetool`. If you have Xcode installed with the iPhone OS 2.2 SDK in the default location (/Developer/Platforms/), then `texturetool` is located at: `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/texturetool`.
>
> `texturetool` allows you to create four variants of `PVRTC` data, the primary difference being tradeoffs between quality and size. You will have to experiment with these variants to determine which setting is the best compromise for each individual texture image.

- [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html)

[HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html) is some same code to help once you have your `pvrtc` file

[HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1611/_index.html) are some more docs

[HERE](http://blog.imgtec.com/powervr/pvrtc-the-most-efficient-texture-compression-standard-for-the-mobile-graphics-world) is a good read on `PVRTC` stuff